# c# : how to identify from which childform was a button (belonging to a parentForm) clicked on?

Tags: c#, forms, inheritance

I have 4 ChildForm(1..4) whose base class is the ParentForm.

ParentForm has a button .

Is there a way to know  from which ChildForm was the button actually clicked?

Comment: in the click event handler can you do something like  `if((sender as Button).Parent == child1)`  ?

Answer (score 0):

Controls have a [Parent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.parent.aspx) or [Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.page.aspx) property, can you use one of those?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with a bit of reflection you can do it. In the eventhandler user the `sender` object to get the type of the parent:

```
Type ChildFormType = ((Button)sender).Parent.GetType();
```

However, having to use reflection (query the type system) is often a sign of bad design. Some kind of [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) implementation where the `ParentForm` as an abstract `accept` method might be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you have got 4 different classes for your 4 forms, all derived from the ParentForm. If this is the case, I would implement the ButtonClicked method in this way:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // part common to all the forms (possibly void)
        specific_button1_Click(sender, e);
        // part common to all the forms (possibly void)
    }

    protected void specific_button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

and then override the specific_button1_Click method in the derived forms